# How do I determined QR code ISO standard?

Tags: qr-code, iso

AS I know, QR code ISO standard have 2 types:

- ISO/IEC 18004:2006
- ISO/IEC 18004:2015

Suppose I have a QR code, how can I check its ISO standard?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: The 2015 edition of ISO/IEC 18004 superseded the 2006 edition, which was withdrawn.